# Is 預けがね a possible reading of 預け金? 預けがね vs 預けきん meanings?

Tags: multiple-readings

Here is the exact line from a translation that I am reading:

> 瓶を店に返して**預け金**の５セントを戻してもらいました。

I just read it as **あずけがね** and continued on. Then, I decided to double check the meaning in my dictionary. But it had it read as **あずけきん**. And that reading seemed strange.

So, this is a professional translation. So, I am pretty sure that:
(1) **あずけがね** is the proper reading for this context.
(2) **あずけがね** does not sound slang.
(3) **あずけきん** is a *proper noun* that is almost exclusively used with regard to apartment rentals?

Comment: Aren't those two words the same thing?

Comment: `that reading seemed strange` Why? The reading あずけ**がね** sounds quite strange to my native ear.

Comment: "あずけきん" is a (kun-yomi sound) then an (on-yomi sound) in the same word. To this non-native, that sounded strange, but not anymore! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

預け金 should be read あずけきん、which means a deposit, security money, or down payment that you can appropreate it to the future payment and settlement, or be refunded by the trustee (shops, dealers, banks, etc) upon the depositor's request, or when the deal is completed.

You can use it colloquially as 銀行への預け金 instead of 銀行預金.
From the trustee's stand, it's called 預り金(きん）.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some related info...

This kind of "unusual" mixing of on-yomi and kun-yomi happens often with finance-related words.

```
On-yomi in katakana, kun-yomi in hiragana:
```

> 売掛金{うりかけキン} - accounts receivable
>
> 買掛金{かいかけキン} - accounts payable
>
> 赤伝{あかデン} - debit slip
>
> 黒伝{くろデン} - credit slip
>
> 支払う{シはらう} - expend, pay out
>
> 相場{ソウば} - market value
>
> 残高{ザンだか} - (bank account) balance

Answer (score 1):

[預]{あず}け[金]{きん} means a security deposit for renting an apartment and [金]{きん} means money. I think you are confused with 預かり金 which is another term for 預け金.

I have never heard anyone use 預けがね for 預け金, but I am not a native Japanese speaker.

Comment: yes. I see. As I was flipping through my dictionaries, I got confused. I have re-written the question.